# Java retrieve next similar item from database

Tags: java, swing, jdbc

I have the following peice of code:

```
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.Orac.   leDriver");

  Connectioncon=DriverManager.getCon.  nection       ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost1521:","sys.   tem","zed");

 String pb=pricebox.getText();

 int pbs=Integer.parseInt(pb);

final PreparedStatement             ps=con.prepareStatement("selectitem   code,remaining    fromshoppingmallproducts   wheretype='"+typebox.getSelectedIte(+.    "',brand='"+brandbox.getSelectedIt.  +'"');

   final      PreparedStatementps=con.prepareStat.    ement("select     itemcode,remainingfrom     shoppingmallproducts where type=and        brand=? and price>=?");



  ps.setString(1(String)typebox.getSelect.     editem();
  ps.setString(2,          (String)brandbox.getSelectedItem());


ps.setInt(3,pbs);


 final ResultSet     rs=ps.executeQuery();
rs.next();

itm=rs.getString("itemcode");


int rem=rs.getInt("remaining");

final String     remm=String.valueOf(rem);


jta1.append("\n "+itm+"\n"+rem+"\n");
```

// jta is the name of the jtextpane used to append data

```
next.addActionListener(new     ActionListener()

{
public void

 actionPerformed(ActionEvent as)
{
try {


jta1.removeAll();

jta1.setText("");

rs.next();


String itm=rs.getString("itemcode");



int prc=rs.getInt("price");




int rem=rs.getInt("remaining");


String remm=String.valueOf(rem);




jta1.append("\n "+itm+"\n"+rem.   +"\n");


  drawimage(itm);



 }
```

Now the question belongs to my next button.
As you can see, the next button will move the result set object to the next row. But I want it to perform it the other way. Now suppose, I choose Levis as brand price range 2000 and type casual shoes. Now suppose I have 3 such products. The first time when I click go button, it will show the first result. Now I want that when I click next, I want the second product with specified features, and so the third product.
Is there any way to do this? Please help me. I am really stuck with this as this is the last task in my college project.
I hope I have clearly explained every thing. Thanx

Comment: Please format your code using the edit function.

Comment: Edited...now can I please get a solution?

Comment: This is unreadable, beside that there are errors in the code. `oracle.jdbc.driver.Orac.   leDriver` (with lots of spaces) or `selectitem` (instead of `select item`) will throw an exception. Please also intend the code properly and remove unnecessary linebreaks.

Comment: @Uooo my code works perfectly.. Its just I have typed here just a fragment of it so it might seem error some to you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your question is not very clear. But I shall try to answer from what I understand.

## first about rs.next();

This cursor is a pointer that points to one row of data in the ResultSet. Initially, the cursor is positioned before the first row. The method ResultSet.next moves the cursor to the next row. This method returns false if the cursor is positioned after the last row.

So rs.next() points to the result obtained from running your query. Let us say your table has 10 rows in total and then your query return 5 rows from that, depending on the conditions you have specified in the query(like brand,price etc ) . In such a case the rs will point to the 5 rows returned for your query. It will be pointed to before the first row of the result. when you do rs.next(); it should return the first row of the 5 rows returned as result. every rs.next() henceforth will return the next row from the 5 result rows. when rs points to 5th row and you do rs.next() then it will return false and you will know that not more rows exist to be returned.

if you are not getting value in this manner , most probable reason is your query. Try printing out all the rows returned from query using code

```
while (rs.next()) {
            int itm = rs.getString("itemcode");
            int price = rs.getString("price");
            int remaining = rs.getString("remaining");

            System.out.println(itm + "\t" + price +
                               "\t" + remaining );
        }
```

this will print the result to the console for you to debug.

If this is printing the correct result then your query is correct. May be the problem is that rs value in jtextpane is incorrect and not pointing correctly as it should be.

PS : variable type  of price should be double
Also if your question was just about order of returned result you could use ORDER BY with your query. it will allow the result to be returned according to the sorted order (ascending or descending based on a column ) of the table

Comment: @raj...thanx for your help...from what you said I get that if I get 5 rows as Ans, it will print first the data for the first row...then it will print the data for the second row,even if the data is not that I want??

Comment: what i means is if your database table has 10 products ( 5 levis,5 pepe) and your query is where product == levis then 5 rows will be returned all of which is levis. and rs will point to the. beginning of 5 rows with levis.

Comment: Thanx a lot @raj..that sure solved my problem..:) as always..stack overflow and it's experts rock

Comment: if my answer helped you , please click accept answer or upvote the answer . Always happy to help :-)

Comment: M sorry raj I don't have 15 reps...but lot of thanx again for your help...

Comment: you do not need 15 reps to accept the answer. select big tick mark near the answer(left). you could also. answer your own question and accept it if the real answer is different. That will make the question  marked as answered.

Comment: Done :) well my question taught me a lot than expected..lolz